# WAMP stack installation on Windows 8 - not turning red or yellow

Tags: apache, wampserver

Distribution: [wampserver.com](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#wampserver-32-bits-php5-3)

I have installed wamp on windows 8. Wamp is not turning into orange or green color. Whenever I test port 80 from apache > service >test port 80..I get message "your port not actually used". I don't have skype installed.

When I open  `http://127.0.0.1/ " or  http://localhost/` I get error message "server not found" in firefox and chrome.

I have tried apache > service > install service..But when it(cmd window) asks:- to press enter to continue, it gets disappear ..Nothing is working right.!!

No error log is generating in apache > apache_error_log ..

my host file contains following line only:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
```

Thank you...

Comment: which WAMP stack? can you provide the link?

Comment: http://www.wampserver.com/en/#wampserver-32-bits-php5-3    this is from where i downloaded  wampserver2.2e-php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-32b

Comment: both VC9 & VC9-SP1 libraries installed?

Comment: thank you for your help..Now its okay. after installing VC9-SP1. Wamp turns to green.